# How many messages needs to be send to server to get AES key in Cache-timing Attack

Tags: aes, side-channel-attack

I'm trying to evaluate the correlation between key length and the number of messages that needs to be send to server during Cache timing Attack.

I read both
D. Bernstein, [“Cache-timing attacks on AES,”](http://cr.yp.to/antiforgery/cachetiming-20050414.pdf) April 2005. Department of Mathematics, Statistics, and Computer Science University of Illinois at Chicago.
Robert G. Salembier, ["Analysis of Cache Timing Attacks against AES"](http://teal.gmu.edu/courses/ECE746/project/F06_Project_resources/Salembier_Cache_Timing_Attack.pdf)

But it doesn't give me the answer. 
At the beginning Bernstein identified one byte of key after sending around 4,2 million 400-byte long messages. Attack described was done on the 128-bit AES key, and it required 32 million 800-byte packages, 32 million 600 byte packets, and 128 million 400-byte packets. But in conclusions (Future works) D.Bernstein write: "I wouldn't be surprised if the first million (2^20) 800-byte and 600-byte packets were sufficient to identify the key"

Additional information can be found in [[7]](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/papers/ssl-timing.pdf). But there is still no direct correlation between key length and message numbers.

Is there any correlation ?

Comment: Depends a lot on how well you can measure the timing. Bernstein used a setup with pretty accurate timing information.